# Equivalent queries => identical JQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have `<element id="blah" class="blah" attr="blah">` (edit: and I have NO other elements in the DOM, just this one)

Then are these jQuery objects absolutely equivalent:

```
$("#blah")
$(".blah")
$("[attr=blah]")
```

Is it the case that the query is executed when the object is created and after that it is irrelevant what query was used?

Edit: Does the original query used have any impact later on anything I might do with the resulting jQuery object? Are the 3 resulting objects above identical? Are they any lasting effects from the actual query I had used? (e.g., when I do something with that object later)

Comment: Assuming you don't have any other elements with the `blah` class or that attribute value - then yes, the selector is irrelevant.

Comment: ... it depends what other elements you have on the page.

Comment: I don't understand your last question.

Comment: This question was edited to be *crystal clear* what the OP was asking and 3 minutes later put on hold for being unclear.

Comment: @James: The OP did not change the last part of the question which I'm still having trouble figuring out especially given the vague stub of code (and it would seem that I'm not the only one who doesn't understand it). Maybe you can help.

Comment: @BoltClock My comment wasn't directed at you sir.  The clarifying edit came well after your justified comment, but before it was put on hold.  My interpretation: if those three queries are executed and their results assigned to variables, is there any action (DOM manipulation, changing `attr=blah` to `attr=notblah`, removing class, etc) that can cause those variables to point to a different element, more than one element, zero elements?

Comment: @James Also: binding events to that object or doing any operation on that object itself that might be less efficient somehow because the original query was less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Each may get the element, however they do it in different ways because they are different selectors.

The id selector `#`

```
$("#blah")
```

This will return a jQuery object with *1* element in it (the element you list). The benefit of using an id is that it will only return your one element if it exists, and is fastest as a result of ids being expected to be unique.

The class selector `.`

```
$('.blah')
```

This will return a jQuery object with an array of elements in it (including the element you lsit), but also with any other element that has this class. Since there is no combination with this selector, it will be slower than a straight id lookup because it must inspect every element on the page for this class.

The attribute selector `[]`

```
$("[attr=blah]")
```

Much like the class selector, this will return an array of elements. It also must inspect every element.

---

These may look the same if there is only one match when a jQuery function call is used. The reason for that happening is jQuery will look to see if there is an array of elements matched, and then internally use `$.each` on the set to apply the jQuery function call to them. The benefit is that this makes sets of elements responds very similarly to single elements which are wrapped by the jQuery object.

Here is a whole list of selectors jQuery supports:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: In my example, I meant that all the selectors will match just this one element: {element id="blah" class="blah" attr="blah"}.

Answer (score 1):

The element will match all three selectors, but it does not make the three selectors absolutely equivalent because they all have different matching criteria (one looks for an ID, one looks for a class name, and one looks for an arbitrary attribute). In particular, the class and attribute selectors can return more than one element, since unlike an ID selector they do not imply uniqueness of an element.

Even if you can guarantee that this element will be the *only* one matched by all three selectors, every call to `$` always yields a unique jQuery object, even if the resulting jQuery objects encapsulate the same DOM element.

Comment: Are the resulting object identical? Are they any lasting effects from  the actual query I had used? (e.g., when I do something with that object later)

Answer (score 0):

The query returns an array of html elements. In this specific case all queries return the same array. There is no way the original query will have an effect later.